# php prepared statements - newbie

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to insert into a table call log at set of values using mysqli prepared statements. I have 2 functions save_timecard_entry which, if I use all the POST data inserts without a problem. 
However I have a second function where I am trying to look up an id from another table called clients and then use this id to insert into the first table.
Cannot seem to get it to work

```
$this->conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) etc.....

function save_timecard_entry(){
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $client = fetch_id($_POST['client']);
        $job = $_POST['job'];
        $task = $_POST['task'];
        $time = $_POST['time'];
        $username = 2;

        $query = "INSERT INTO log VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)){
            $stmt->bind_param('siiiii', $date, $client, $job, $task, $time, $username);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }
    } else{
        echo 'error' . $this->conn->error;
    }


}

function fetch_id($name){
    if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, FROM clients WHERE name =?")){
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $name);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id);
        $stmt->fetch();
        return $id;
        $stmt->close;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only one parameter that needs to be bound but you're passing a data type string with 2 letters.

The correct `bind_param` call:

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
```

I would also do some kind of error checking, it is very likely that `$stmt->bind_param()` returned `false`, you would want to check for that before actually executing the query.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't executed it, but there's a comma after "id" which must be removed from the query in order to work as expected:

```
    if ($stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM clients WHERE name = ?")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems, one of which has already been mentioned.  In the second query you are binding two string variables, "ss", but you only have one variable in the query.

Also, in the first query you are binding parameters as "siiiii".  That is one string followed by five integers.  However, one of your parameters is a value for $time, that you are apparently getting from a form post.  How is that $time variable being generated in your form?  Php time() returns an integer, but if you are allowing people to enter times such as 11:30pm in the form, then that would be a string rather than an integer.  The query would not work properly if you are trying to bind a string as an integer.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use `PDOStatement->bindParam` like that. If you would like to bind all your parameters at once, you can use `PDOStatement->execute` instead, since it takes an array with the params:

```
$stm->execute(array($date, $client, $job, $task, $time, $username));
```

Comment: He's using ```mysqli```, not ```PDO```.

Comment: Who said anything about this being PDO?  The connection object is `mysqli`